# Why i get an console key error after mapping Array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am developing a react app where I have an array of objects.I map the Objects in React like this

```
<ListGroup id="building_list">
              {this.state.buildings.map(item => {
                return (
                  <ListGroupItem className="booking_list_group " key={item.id}>
                    <Container
                      className="booking_building my-auto "
                      fluid={true}
                    >
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs={4} className="text-center my-auto">
                          <FaWarehouse id="booking_icon"></FaWarehouse>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={6} className=" my-auto ">
                          {" "}
                          <div>{item.name}</div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={2} className="my-auto ">
                          {" "}
                          <div
                            className="test"
                            onClick={event => this.completeBuidling(item.id)}
                          ></div>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Container>
                  </ListGroupItem>
                );
              })}
            </ListGroup>
```

After this the List gets displayed and it works fine.The only problem is that i get an Error in in the Console[image]

Ok now there is the Array
[image]

What could be the problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: @EugenSunic : it looks like OP ***has*** assigned the key

Comment: No in every case in the whole application and every object has an id

Comment: @LeonGreiner : just for the sake of clarity, show us the excerpt from `this.state.buildings` to demonstrate your sourcing objects have `id` property

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov ok i have logged the array into the console

Comment: @LeonGreiner : than your code should [work](https://jsfiddle.net/9sz1xdy0/1/) perfectly fine (in slightly shortcircuited form, though) and I would recommend you to set up a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) to reproduce your issue and get some ideas about what may possibly go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

extract everything what you return to map function into a separate Component and just pass props - then you can use only one `key`

```
const ListGroupItemRow = ({fluid, name, id}) => (
<ListGroupItem className="booking_list_group ">
                    <Container
                      className="booking_building my-auto "
                      fluid={true}
                    >
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs={4} className="text-center my-auto">
                          <FaWarehouse id="booking_icon"></FaWarehouse>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={6} className=" my-auto ">
                          {" "}
                          <div>{name}</div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={2} className="my-auto ">
                          {" "}
                          <div
                            className="test"
                            onClick={event => this.completeBuidling(id)}
                          ></div>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Container>
                  </ListGroupItem>
)
```

and then use

```
{this.state.buildings.map(item => (<ListGroupItemRow ...item key={item.id} />))}
```

I didn't test it of course but I'm adding it because I was asked to be more specific and verbose.

Comment: sure I can make it clearer. I'll amend my answer in a moment to be more verbose. But can you explain me what do you mean by "OP"?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov no code manually. I updated my answer is that make sense now? Hope it's enough verbose what I suggested

Comment: aside, from your last line should rather contains something more like `<ListGroupItemRow {...{...item key: item.id}} />`, I don't see how your suggested solution may behave differently from what OP currently has

Answer (score 0):

Your example should be working. Are you sure that the error doesn't refer to an other mapping? The error message says `div`, and (assuming you use Reactstrap) `ListGroupItem`'s render `li` elements, so maybe you forgot to include keys somewhere else in your application.

Answer (score -1):

just add the key like this. but i think it should work for the above code

```
          <ListGroup id="building_list">
              {this.state.buildings.map((item,index) => {
                return (
                  <ListGroupItem className="booking_list_group " key={index}>
                    <Container
                      className="booking_building my-auto "
                      fluid={true}
                    >
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs={4} className="text-center my-auto" key={"col1"+index}>
                          <FaWarehouse id="booking_icon"></FaWarehouse>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={6} className=" my-auto " key={"col2"+index}>
                          {" "}
                          <div>{item.name}</div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={2} className="my-auto " key={"col3"+index}>
                          {" "}
                          <div
                            className="test"
                            onClick={event => this.completeBuidling(item.id)}
                          ></div>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Container>
                  </ListGroupItem>
                );
              })}
            </ListGroup>
```

Comment: OP *has* assigned `key` prop, moreover, using array indexes as a key is [less preferable](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) than unique property (like `id`, used by OP) of a sourcing object